# Null-Pointer Exception while using AOP

Tags: spring-mvc, aspectj, resteasy

application context file

```
    <!-- Aspect -->
    <!-- It allow @Component, @Service, @Controller, etc.. annotations -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.piyush.cns.*" />
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>


    <!-- It allow us to use @Autowire, @Required and @Qualifier annotations -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Logger bean -->
    <bean id="logger" class="org.slf4j.LoggerFactory" factory-method="getLogger">
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="com.piyush.cns" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Aspect -->
    <bean id="logAspect" class="com.piyush.cns.customer.resource.AllAspects" /> 
</beans>
```

Above code is the application context file which contain all the bean declaration.

Controller Class  CustomersResource . This class will receive the request initially. Basic requirement is to validate the customer object from server side.

```
@Controller
@Path("/customers")
public class CustomersResource implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Autowired
    ICustomerService customerService;

    @Autowired
    IPartnerService partnerService;

    @Autowired
    ResourceHelper resourceHelper;

    @Autowired
    private Logger logger;

    /**
     * @Request POST
     * @param uriInfo - To get Absolute path
     * @param Customer - JSON Request of Customer to add
     * @return Response with created customer Payload.  Also includes location header
     * @throws TCException - If customer Name already exist
     * @Description REST service to add Customer sent as JSON
     */
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response addCustomer(@Context UriInfo uriInfo, Customer customer) throws TCException {
        logger.info("Entering addCustomer for customer " + customer.getCustomerName());
        logger.debug("customer Desc \t " + customer.getDescription());

        MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParams = uriInfo.getQueryParameters();
        String partnerId = queryParams.getFirst("partnerId");
        logger.info("Partner ID from Query Param : " + partnerId);
        // If partnerId : Null, Customer type is direct ie, not associated with any partner. implies customer type = 0
        // [Direct]
        if (null == partnerId) {
            // Add DIRECT Customer
            customer.setCustomerType(0);
            logger.debug("Customer type set to : DIRECT");
        } else {
            // ADD INDIRECT Customer
            // Set customer type, partner
            customer.setCustomerType(1);
            logger.debug("Customer type set to : INDIRECT");
            // Check if partner exist
            Partner partner = partnerService.getPartnerById(Long.parseLong(partnerId));
            if (null == partner) {
                logger.error("EntityResourceNotFoundException. Partner Resource not found for ID : " + partnerId);
                throw new EntityResourceNotFoundException("", "Partner Resource with ID : " + partnerId
                    + " not found to add customer");
            }
            customer.setPartner(partner);
            logger.debug("Customer set to Partner : " + partnerId);
        }
        // Save Customer
        customer = customerService.addCustomer(customer);

        // Creating location header
        UriBuilder builder = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder();
        URI uri = builder.path(String.valueOf(customer.getId())).build();
        logger.info("Exiting addCustomer for customer " + customer.getCustomerName());
        return Response
            .created(URI.create(uri.toString()))
            .entity(
                resourceHelper.buildResponse(customer, Status.CREATED.toString(),
                    "Customer Created: " + customer.getCustomerName())).build();
    }



Aspect class AllAspects

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.*;

@Aspect
public class AllAspects {

    @Before("execution(* com.piyush.cns.customer.resource.CustomersResource.addCustomer(..))")
    public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {

        System.out.println("logBefore() is running!");
        System.out.println("******");
    }
}




My problem is the control flow is not going inside the method "logBefore(...)"of class AllAspects and also in class CustomersResource  at the method addCustomers(...) logger is coming as null.


Please help me get out of this issue.
```

Comment: Where exactly is this error occurring? If possible, post the stack-trace.

Comment: also the Aspect code...